# PHP socket server that uses ADH. How?

Tags: php, sockets, ssl

I'm trying to create a socket server using [stream_socket_server()](http://php.net/stream_socket_server).

Normal connections work fine, but I want to make a server that encrypts the connection without a certificate. I know that this can be accomplished with the ADH cipher, and yes, I know it's theoretically less secure than with a certificate...

The reason I'm making this server in the first place is to mock a different server to which a client connects to (over [this protocol](http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:API-SSL), if you're wondering).

The client is configured to ask for a certificate first, and fallback to ADH - I've tested it with the real thing, and it connects without problems, so the problem is with the socket server.

Everything I've tried so far has resulted in a "handshake failure" error.

Some of the configurations I've tried:

```
<?php
$server = stream_socket_server(
        "tls://127.0.0.1:6667",
        $errorno,
        $errstr,
        STREAM_SERVER_BIND | STREAM_SERVER_LISTEN,
        stream_context_create(
            array('ssl' => array('ciphers' => 'ADH'))
        )
    );
?>

<?php
$server = stream_socket_server(
        "tls://127.0.0.1:6667",
        $errorno,
        $errstr,
        STREAM_SERVER_BIND | STREAM_SERVER_LISTEN,
        stream_context_create(
            array('ssl' => array('ciphers' => '-COMPLEMENTOFALL ADH'))
        )
    );
?>
```

I've also tried to adjust the client to unconditionally use ADH (as with the second example above), just for testing's sake, but that too fails.

This happens with every PHP version I've tried, the latest of which is 5.5.0.

Any ideas?

Comment: see this may be be help you http://christophh.net/2012/07/24/php-socket-programming/

Comment: @krishna That article doesn't even mention encryption, and given that the unencrypted connection works fine, it doesn't help at all.

Answer (score 5):

I would use a tool like Wireshark to examine the bits going over the wire so I could determine exactly what is going wrong with the handshake. Without that ability, you are going to be flying (or debugging) blind.

Once you know what is going wrong with your handshake, you can figure out the "why".

Comment: For some reason, Wireshark doesn't capture the traffic from my computer back to itself. This is even when I replace "127.0.0.1" with my computer's (public) IP. I'll try to set up a secondary computer, and see if that does the trick...

Comment: The raw bytes can be seen here https://gist.github.com/boenrobot/6331636

As far as how Wireshark decodes this - the hello packet contains ADH ciphers only (as expected for this particular test), and the server replies with "handshake failure (40)".

Comment: Oh, and on the client, the following error message is shown: "error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure". (odd... I'm using TLS on both peers, not SSLv3)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly check that SSL is setup correctly in your server? [Run SSL Scanner](http://wiki.cacert.org/SSLScanner)  at the service.   I have a test script that doesn't work at all, as the OpenSSL calls don't run without a key file.  This isn't an answer, but I lack time for more investigation...

You are aware that ADH is a weak encryption? ~ most of the security advisories recommend turning it off.  General reading on ADH http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:Ciphers(1)

Comment: Yes. As I said at the top, I'm aware that ADH is less secure than a connection with a certificate, and I'm trying to create a server as a mock in a unit test, not for "production" use. The real server supports ADH as an alternative when the server has no certificate. As for SSLScan... I ran [the Windows port of SSLScan](http://code.google.com/p/sslscan-win/), and after slightly adjusting the script to stream_socket_accept() again even on failure, I see all ciphers as "Rejected" with the server sending back the exact same packet as previously noted.

Comment: BTW, interesting thing to note... with the test server as above, I get only the TLSv1 and SSLv3 ciphers as "Rejected", and SSLv2 as "Failed". When I place an empty file as the "local_cert" context option, I also get the SSLv2 ciphers as "Rejected".

Comment: empty local cert... I would expect that. As this is written from a security point of view; an empty file is the same as an invalid cert that rejects everyone.

Comment: If I have everything I am doing done; I will spend more time on Tues.